# version in package-lock file of a dependency is being ignored

Tags: npm, node-modules

I am importing a dependency in my package.json.  That dependency has it's own `package-lock.json` file in which a the versions of its own dependencies are written.  However, when I do my `npm install ... --save`, the version of the dependency's dependency is not the right one, npm is picking up the latest version. It seems to be ignoring the lock file that belongs to the dependency.

So my dependency contains this in it's `package.json` file: `"ccxt": "^1.52.41"`. And in it's `package-lock.json` there is `... "ccxt": { "version": "1.52.41"...`.

When I add this dependency to my project, the version of ccxt that gets installed (the version in my lock file) is `1.52.94`.

What am I doing wrong?

Using npm v6.14.13

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the package-lock files that belong to your dependencies are ignored by npm.  This is by "design" apparently.  So at `npm install` time, you will essentially get a totally random bunch of dependencies installed and added to your package-lock file.  From that point on those dependencies are fixed by your lock file until you manually update them using the npm command line.

This means that if you are unlucky and install at a 'bad' time, like I did, then you will pick up some completely untested code that could be broken and/or incompatible with its parent project or your project.